# IPhone- marking an icon or button with a number to indicate new activity like mail app

Tags: iphone

I am wanting to display a number on top of an icon when a user receives a new message, similar to the mail app and sms app when new messages are received (the red number on top of the icon) (btw i want to do it inside my app not on the icon on the home screen)... I know i  can just have a  little image with every number and draw it on top of an icon or button, but i was wondering if there was any built in API that can do this already?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what interface element you're using. If you're using a tab tab (`UITabBar`) you'll find that `UITabBarItem`s have a `badgeValue` property that you can set to some text to display in a red circle as you describe. Unfortunately you might have to do it "by hand" if you're using a different element.

Comment: cool i actually wanted to do i t on a tab bar icon...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/04/open-iphone-sdk-adding-applica.html) explains the api to add application badges

Answer (score 0):

This little bit of code may be easier:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:theIntToDisplay];
```

Comment: what does this display the badge on?

Comment: This will set the badge on the application icon (in spring board, ie. outside your app), like the Mail app does for unread messages.